# When I attempt to login to my web app, I receive a "Subscript out of range" error

Tags: authentication, asp-classic

After entering in the correct password and hitting Login, I immediately receive a "Subscript out of Range" error.

Any ideas on why this happens and what steps I can take to resolve it?

Any help or details you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because you are referencing a non-existent index in an array or collection.

e.g. The array has 3 items in it and the code is referring to a 4th.

Array indexes are normally base zero, so to reference the first item you would do this:

Array(0).

If looping you will need something like this:

```
For i = 0 to Array.Count - 1
   strOutput = strOutput & Array(i).ToString
Next
```

It would help if you run the application in debug mode and see which line it fails on.